# How to define .htaccess rule in PHP

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

**I want to add rules in my .htaccess file to redirect my application.**

Let me present the problem by an example :

If user types in the URL => `www.myNewProduct.com` 
then redirect URL is => `www.myNewProduct.com/index.php`

And if the user type => `www.myNewProduct.com/customer` 
Then redirect URL is => `www.myNewProduct.com/API/MNP/customerService`

My .htaccees file is :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(([a-zA-Z0-9\-=&]*))
RewriteRule ^Login/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*)$ Login.php?LicenseType=$1&Refresh=1/$1

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(([/docusign))
RewriteRule ^Login/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*)$ Login.php?LicenseType=$1&Refresh=1/$1
```

How to accomplish the task **in question** ?

Comment: And what problem do you have expressing this as a rewrite rule?

Comment: I dont have any Idia how to define rules in htaccess file for multiple url

Comment: Your first "rule" isn't mod rewrite at all just the DirectoryIndex, so there is only one rule in the question. If you've tried _nothing_ - start by trying _something_

Comment: THis is my htaccess file{                                                       Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(([a-zA-Z0-9\-=&]*))
RewriteRule ^Login/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*)$ Login.php?LicenseType=$1&Refresh=1/$1

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(([/docusign))
RewriteRule ^Login/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*)$ Login.php?LicenseType=$1&Refresh=1/$1}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "define" htaccess rewrite rules in PHP, what you could do is to set all urls to be handled by the index.php like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?requested=$1 [L]
```

In php you could fetch the ful url with `$_GET['requested']`, you can then do further processing.

You should definitely take a look at htaccess/rewriterules.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named `.htaccess` on the root directory of your domain, then add the following code to it:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php # define the index page.
RewriteEngine On # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule ^customer$ /API/MNP/customerService [NC,L] # Handle requests for "customer"
```

Answer (score 0):

Put in .htaccess file:

```
# Redirect main domain to index.php
Redirect / index.php

# Redirect www.myNewProduct.com/customer to www.myNewProduct.com/API/MNP/customerService
Redirect /customer /API/MNP/customerService
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteRule ^customer$ http://www.myNewProduct.com/API/MNP/customerService [R]
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a [DirectoryIndex](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/directoryindex-uses/) command to your htaccess file.